# How to implement that certain buttons appear for a while when I move the mouse and then dissaper if mouse is still?

Tags: wpf, mousemove

I used `MouseMove` event to detect mouse movement, so I could change the visibility of my buttons. After the mouse has stopped moving, the buttons are still there, because I don't know how and where to count for the time to make those buttons invisible again.

Those buttons are controls on video player in full screen, so any other idea is also welcomed.

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();

        button1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        button2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    private void mediaElement1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!timer.Enabled)
        {
            timer.Enabled = true;
            return;
        }
        if (timer.Enabled)
        {
            timer.Interval = 2000;
            timer.Start();

            button1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            button2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to utilize some form of timer, such as the [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) class. You can then hook up to the [`Elapsed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx) event and use the handler inside there to count the time elapsed. Once you reach a certain time threshold, you can then hide the buttons. So an example of the code steps would be something like:

1. User moves mouse.
2. Show buttons.
3. User stops moving mouse.
4. Start timer.
5. Count time on `Timer.Elapsed` event.
6. Time count reaches threshold.
7. Hide buttons and stop the timer.

[image: Activity Diagram Showing Events and Process]

Comment: I'm still newbie, should I capture when the mouse stops moving inside MouseMove method, or somewhere else?

Comment: You will probably want to actually start the timer inside the `MouseMove` event handler, and reset the timer each time you enter that method. I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Oh, I've just found clear example for [using timer event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx) at MSDN

Comment: Which means I should create a timer as a member of a class and not as a member of a MouseMove handler (speaking about reseting timer every time)?

Comment: @HomeMade Yes, that is correct. See my edited answer for a *very* rough diagram illustrating the process that you should follow.

Comment: Great diagram, thanks! I don't know nothing about threshold, what and how to do with it?  I thought Timer.ElapsedEvent should handle the hidding of buttons, but you draw that it's a branch of Time at Threshold condition :/

Comment: By that, I simply mean something like maintaining a global variable in your class that you add 1 to each time you handle the `Timer.Elapsed` event. Then, if you define some threshold value as 100 (for example), when your variable reaches or exceeds that value, then you can consider that as reaching some time threshold.

Comment: Ok, so far I have created timer and 'ElapsedEventHandler' (check out my edit), but it tells that lines that are setting Visibility cannot be executed for 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6650/discussion-between-homemade-and-samuel-slade)